# Magento 2: Cannot observe controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a standard Observer setup, the module does nothing else. If I change the event it's listening for to `controller_action_predispatch`, the Observer activates as normal. With `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index` and no other changes, it does not.

I'm looking at the output from the M2 profiler; I can see both events being fired. My only clue is that there is another Observer on the same event (from a different module). I've looked at the source for this Observer, and it doesn't seem to do anything important.
[profiler screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fvRv.jpg)

I also used a standard `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` instance to check the Observer can fire at all.

**Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index">
        <observer name="vendor_module_requirelogin"
                  instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\RequireLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Observer/RequireLogin.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class RequireLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $responseFactory;
    protected $session;
    protected $url;

    public function __construct(
        ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        UrlInterface $url,
        Session $session
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!$this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $url = $this->url->getUrl('customer/account/login');
            return $this->responseFactory->create()
                ->setRedirect($url)
                ->sendResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try disabling the other observer/module to rule it out as a potential issue. Does the problem still persist?